# Jquery: Getting the same img src on different images

Tags: jquery, html, image, src

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="imgModal"><img src="1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="imgModal"><img src="2.jpg" /></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="imgModal"><img src="3.jpg" /></a>
<div class="modal">
<img src="" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
var link = $(".imgModal");
var modal = $(".modal");
var img = $(".modal img");
var src = $("img",this).attr("src");

link.click(function(){
    modal.css({"display":"block"});
    img.attr("src", src);
});

modal.click(function(){
    modal.css({"display":"none"});
});
});
```

The idea is obvious the img src in the modal div img should be the same as the img that the user has clicked, the thing is I only get the same image src on all three of the images when I click.Any ideas?

---- FIXED ----

Marc Anton Dahmen suggested the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var   link = $(".imgModal"),
      modal = $(".modal"),
      img = $(".modal img");

link.click(function(){
    modal.css({"display":"block"});
    img.attr("src", $(this).find("img").attr("src"));
});

modal.click(function(){
    modal.css({"display":"none"});
});
});
```

Comment: here `this` Is not specific:   `var src = $("img",this).attr("src");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var   link = $(".imgModal"),
          modal = $(".modal"),
          img = $(".modal img");

    link.click(function(){
        modal.css({"display":"block"});
        img.attr("src", $(this).find("img").attr("src"));
    });

    modal.click(function(){
        modal.css({"display":"none"});
    });
});
```

Get the src in the click function.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `var src = $("img",this).attr("src");` to `var src = $(this).find('img').attr("src");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone now, so can't test it at the moment.  However, you are setting the source on page load instead of the click. Try moving the src -row into the click action instead.

```
link.click(function(){
  modal.css({"display":"block"});
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  img.attr("src", src);
});
```